# Import issues in Python

Tags: python, import, module

I am having an import error problem in a test script. It looks like its something to do with the directory structure.

I have the following folder structure:

```
A
├── F1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── Src
│       └── F2
│           └── __init__.py
└── tests1
    └── tests1
        └── test_script.py
```

A/F1/Src/F2

F1 has "__init__py" in its level
F2 has "__init__.py" in its level

In the same level as F1, there is another folder "tests1"

tests1/tests1/test_script.py

in test_script.py, I have a line which says

from F1.src.F2 import C

With the above, I get an error saying, no module named "F1.src.F2"

Does someone know what is going on here?

Comment: Make sure you're using `__init__.py` rather than random permutations, and read the docs on absolute and relative imports.

Comment: @JasonS: I think the random permutations were a formatting error. The raw source of the question had it right. I adjusted the markdown so we can see the actual file name.

Comment: I have an existing project but I did not create source folder and PyDev Project while creating it. How can I make existing folder - source or PyDev Package?

Comment: Try to include an `__init__.py` file in your src folder

Comment: Mart0903 - what will that do apart from making "src" a package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to create a shared library with the "egg" file.

As simple as that but it occurred to me late!

Answer (score 0):

`from F1.src.F2 import C` is an absolute import. In order for it to work, "F1" has to be located somewhere on your Python path (`sys.path`). Generally this also includes the current directory if you ran Python on the command line.

So if the `A` directory is not one of the directories on your Python path and is not your current working directory, there is no reason the import would work.

Module names are case sensitive. You have `Src` in one place and `src` in another, but I'm not sure that reflects your actual directory structure or just what you typed here.

Using a relative import will not work if you are running test_script.py as a script (Which is what it sounds like.) So, what you really want to do is make sure that either you run the script from the `A` directory, or go whole hog, make your project into a legit package with a `setup.py` and use a test runner such as `tox`.

Comment: Jason - Src=src. There is a whole project here and I am not sure how to make my project into a legit package with a setup.py. I see a setup.py in one of the folders in my project.. cud u elaborate?